# What is the limit on number of keys in Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, reducers

I thoroughly searched for an answer, however I am still confused about 
the limit on number of keys or reduce tasks in Hadoop framework. Is it an integer number or can be any value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no limitation in number of keys in map reduce programming.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can you please elaborate on why there is no limit on number of keys?

Answer (score 1):

Hadoop MapReduce works in `Key-Value` pair pattern, and key can be anything the only criteria is key class must be implement `org.apache.hadoop.io.WritableComparable` `interface` and value class must be implementation of `org.apache.hadoop.io.Writable` interface